# Can JQuery UI Dialog remember its position between opening and closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a JQuery dialog that I dynamically open and close. Everything is working fine except the position of the dialog is not remembered after it is closed and then reopened.

The size is maintained but the position is not.

I have tried hooking into the 'Open' event but it appears that the position is being reset by JQuery UI after I manually reposition the element.

Is maintaining the size of the dialog possible? I certainly think it should be.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a sample link?

Comment: You mean http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ?

Comment: Yes - JQuery UI dialog. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the jQuery UI Dialog "beforeclose" event to store the position and size. You can set both position and size using the "option" method.

Here is what currently works for me:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        beforeclose: function(){
            $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [$(this).offset().left, $(this).offset().top]);
            $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $(this).width());
            $(this).dialog('option', 'height', $(this).height());
        }
    });
});
```

$('#dialog').dialog('open')

Comment: I have already attempted this suggestion. When I set the position using the options it appears to not be recognised. Either I am doing something wrong (everything looks ok) or the options are being overidden by the control.

Comment: I updated the answer with tested code. Have another look please.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the standard close method by returning false on 'beforeclose' and using jquery to hide the dialog:

```
$.ui.dialog.defaults.beforeclose = function() {
    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').hide();
    return false;
};
```

and this to reopen:

```
$('#list').closest('.ui-dialog').show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at jquery [changeset](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:e4LRhMcQ80EJ:dev.jqueryui.com/changeset/2961+jquery+ui+remember+dialog+position&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk).
You'll also find a fix for this

Comment: Link is now broken, why was it ever linked to a direct ip address?