# jQuery UI dialog: wrong position if scrollbars are visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-dialog

I have a big container with scrollbars.

A modal dialog with jquery UI shall open in the middle of this container.

The dialog opens, but after closing and opening again and again it **moves** up or down (and so it always has a wrong position).

I've added from this thread [Can JQuery UI Dialog remember its position between opening and closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989759/can-jquery-ui-dialog-remember-its-position-between-opening-and-closing) the following part:

```
beforeclose: function(){
   $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [$(this).offset().left, $(this).offset().top]);
}
```

If I remove this part, then the dialog opens **after dragging/moving it around** alway **on top** of the page.

Also, if the dialog is opened at the bottom, the movings are even crazier.

My code:

```
$("#btnTest").click(function(){
  if ($("#exec").length == 0) {

            $('body').append('<div id="exec" style="width:320px;background-color: #000;display:none;">xxx</div>');

          $("#exec").dialog({
            width: 320,
            modal: true,
            position: "center",
            show: { effect: "slide", direction: "up", duration: 400 },
            hide: { effect: "slide", direction: "up", duration: 400 }
         });
       } else {
            $("#exec").dialog("open");
        }
 });

$("#btnClose").click(function(){
    $("#exec").dialog('close');
});
```

**Check it @ jsfiddle:**
 http://jsfiddle.net/EDkk6/4/

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are not taking in account of the parent div that is created along with the modal itself. If you get the offset of the parent div, everything appears to work correctly. Check out my answer for more info and a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a 20px difference in the top position of the modal when it is reopened. I believe this is because the UI dialog is created within a parent div which you are not taking account for in your offset. Therefore, you need to get the offset based on the parent like so:

```
beforeclose: function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [$parent.offset().left,$parent.offset().top]);
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EDkk6/32/)

Comment: @Keith Does this resolve your problem? Are you still having issues?

Comment: It's working, but only with the on top buttons. With the buttons at the bottom it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line:

```
beforeclose: function(){
   $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [$(this).offset().left, $(this).offset().top]);
}
```

with:

```
beforeclose: function(){
   $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [$(this).offset().left, $(this).offset().top-20]);
                                                                                     ^^ Added -20 with offset().top
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/YZf6Y/)